total solana cost of creating token?
would anyone happen to know the total SOL cost of creating a solana token with spl-token create-token, on the mainnet. i cant seem to find a definite answer for the question online and have seen answers ranging from 0.002 to 3 SOL

mint account = 1461600 lamports
// Get minimum lamports for space required by mint account
const lamports = await getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint(connection);

token account = 2039280 lamports
// Get minimum lamports for space required by token account
const lamports = await getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptAccount(connection);

This is assuming without any extensions enabled from Token Extensions program
